# Styling a <select> using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have recently been told to use select2 to include a search bar in a dropdown list. I am having trouble styling it, any style I attach to the select box doesn't take effect, I am even using !important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to style and how you pick the elements.

In this example i have style the border and input box height. Note this styling will apply for all your select2 boxes

http://jsfiddle.net/2tduypwx/

```
.select2-search__field{
  height:80px;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single{
  border:1px solid red;
  border-radius:0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know what classes to call, is there a list somewhere? Also is there a way to uniquely style each selection? thanks for your response!

Comment: No. I used inspect element to find the classes and change the styling.  Some experience is required to figure out the right class name.

Comment: Oh yes, wasn't thinking thanks for your help!!